# How to exit sudo terminal to normal terminal on mac OS bigSur? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, terminal, sudo, macos-big-sur

**How to exit sudo terminal to normal terminal on macOS bigSur?**

[image]

Comment: Try hitting `exit`

Comment: @PathikPatel when I do so, it prevents me from typing !

Comment: Is there any default command specified on startup ? Check from `Preferences` > `General` Tab > `Shell open with:`

Comment: I have 2 options under `Shell open with:` 
1- Default login shell (selected)
2- Command (complete path):
                        `/bin/zsh`

I tried to select the second option nothing changed after saving the changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are stuck as shown in the screenshot, just hit “Ctrl + c”. This will terminate the current std-reader/process and give you the control.

If you are already signed in to another user with su. You can go back to previous session/user by simply typing “exit”.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tarek, I worked like magic. Actually I tried this before selecting the second option but it didn’t work then. +1 Karma :)